# java application vs java servlet jdbc connection

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, teradata

I have a `Connector` class that works perfect for my java app . However , when I refer to this class from my servlet , i get `classNotFound  .com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver`

So  when i refer to this class from a java class , the db driver gets recognized , but when i refer to this class from a servlet it does not

Comment: Did you have the lib in your WEB-INF\lib folder?

Comment: Have u add jar in the classpath

Comment: Yes, i have included the jar . It works for a regular java project but not for the servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver somewhere in the classpath to make your servlet(eventually Tomcat) recognize this one.
Can be /WEB-INF/classes( if it's single file ) or /WEB-INF/lib ( if it's JAR ) or somewhere under Servlet Container's common classloader path. ( like Tomcat's $TOMCAT_HOME/lib )

Comment: I added it in the class path

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that t he jar file is present in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application.

Comment: i have configured it using `build path - add external jars ` should i in addition to that copy the physical files to the `lib` ?